# do i require transist visa while travelling to USA from manchester terminal 2

Tags: usa, uk, transit, indian-citizens

I am travelling from mumbai to houston via manchester so uk visa is required if the terminal is same?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have US visa, transit visa is not needed for UK for airside transit.